# Could a human body function at a lower mass density?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design

I have a species of humanoid in my story that are very light due to the matter that makes up their bodies having a lower density, I was wondering whether or not this would be realistic.

**My questions are:**

- What problems would come up from the matter in a human body being
  less dense?
- Do certain organs need to be kept the same density to
  function as they do?
- If a human body could function at a lower density, what density would
  it have to reach before it stops functioning?
- Could a very tall but less dense humanoid be able to support its body
  easier due to being lighter?

Comment: Hey, welcome to world building!  This is certainly an interesting premise.

Comment: You've used the [tag:science-based] tag, so your question should offer some scientific basis for answers to expand upon. What are you proposing that the human body should be made of? 70% is water, - some of the lightest elements on the periodic table, the rest - carbon, nitrogen, calcium, sodium and in trace ammounts others like, iron, manganese, magnesium. What would replace these in your [tag:science-based] scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Human body has most of its mass made of the water - about 50%-75%, with proteins at about 10-15%, bones and minerals at max 5% (based on some quick searches)

> What problems would come up from the matter in a human body being less dense?

**A significant** lower body density should mean primarily less water (or an organism using a lighter fluid for sustaining the metabolism; but that would be totally speculative).

Lower water content is likely to be associated with a slower metabolism rate - because water is the main heat sink (both by transporting the heat to the skin to dissipate it and because it has a huge specific heat - 4.8J/g/K). Unless countered by a slower metabolic rate, any other fluid performing these functions will be needed in higher amount and/or higher circulation speed (larger heart).

As a funny after-thought: being tall and slender uses more skin surface for the same volume than being short and closer to a sphere - so, maybe very tall humanoids are a requirement for being less dense?!? Or perhaps developing some leaf-life organs - aren't trees rather tall and slender :) ?

> Do certain organs need to be kept the same density to function as they do?

I don't know - but a slower metabolic rate is likely to require less mass for internal organs to maintain the functions.
Marine birds [have about 60% of they body as water](https://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/files/p0208-p0209.pdf). Most of the birds have a higher body temperature than humans; their body needs to get rid of that heat, even if less water would mean a lower mass and thus less energy required to fly.

> If a human body could function at a lower density, what density would it have to reach before it stops functioning?

Taking "less water" as a way to get to a lower density, Wikipedia says about [dehydration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehydration):

> `Most people can tolerate a 3-4% decrease in total body water without difficulty or adverse health effects. A 5-8% decrease can cause fatigue and dizziness. Loss of over ten percent of total body water can cause physical and mental deterioration, accompanied by severe thirst. Death occurs at a loss of between fifteen and twenty-five percent of the body water.`